# Getting net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT in laravel

Tags: laravel

I've got a brand new installation of laravel 10 and I've run

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

and

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

and

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

I then have this in my console when I go to the login page and registration page

```
GET http://localhost:6000/@vite/client net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT
GET http://localhost:6000/resources/sass/app.css net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT
GET http://localhost:6000/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing.

Comment: The vite server runs on :5173 by default. I don't know how yours got to run on :6000 but you need to change it to something that your browser won't block